# Magento 2 - How to display recently viewed products in customer account sidebar?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, sidebar, recently-viewed

Can anyone tell me how can I show a recently viewed product section in the **customer account sidebar**?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

I have done using below way

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
         <block class="Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Widget\Viewed" before="-" name="recently_viewed" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Reports::widget/viewed/content/viewed_grid.phtml">
                    <action method="setPageSize">
                        <argument name="page_size" xsi:type="number">5</argument>
                    </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```